# Open another app from apple wallet pass

Tags: ios, swift, wallet

I need to add an interactive image in a pass that redirects to my app on tap. This has already been implemented in other apps like Book My Show. But I'm not able to work out how it's done.

Comment: when you click image it should redirect to another app ?this is what you want ?

Comment: Yes it should redirect to the app that generated the pass. Also how can we add that image to the pass.json